# Problems with React native nested if-else

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I created a simple picker that should display OS specifications according to the selected OS when the button is pressed. For example If I selected Windows It should display windows specifications. But I can't figure out how to show the details of the selected item with onPress.

```
import {
  AppForm as Form,
  AppFormPicker as Picker,
  SubmitButton,
} from "../components/forms";

const categories = [
  { label: "Mac", value: 1 },
  { label: "Windows", value: 2 },
  { label: "Linux", value: 3 },
  { label: "Android", value: 4 },
];

const osSpec = () => {
  if (categories.value == 1) {
    return <Text>Mac Specifications</Text>;
  } else if (categories.value == 2) {
    return <Text>Windows Specifications</Text>;
  } else if (categories.value == 3) {
    return <Text>Linux Specifications</Text>;
  } else if (categories.value == 4) {
    return <Text>Android Specifications</Text>;
  } else {
    return <Text>Pick a OS</Text>;
  }
};

function OsSelect(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Form
        initialValues={{
          category: null,
        }}
        onSubmit={(osSpec) => console.log(osSpec)}
      >
        <Picker items={categories} name="category" placeholder="Category" />
        <SubmitButton title="View Specs" onPress={osSpec} />
      </Form>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this please:

```
import {
  AppForm as Form,
  AppFormPicker as Picker,
  SubmitButton,
} from "../components/forms";

const categories = [
  { label: "Mac", value: 1 },
  { label: "Windows", value: 2 },
  { label: "Linux", value: 3 },
  { label: "Android", value: 4 },
];

const osSpec = () => {
  if (categories.value == 1) {
    return <Text>Mac Specifications</Text>;
  } else if (categories.value == 2) {
    return <Text>Windows Specifications</Text>;
  } else if (categories.value == 3) {
    return <Text>Linux Specifications</Text>;
  } else if (categories.value == 4) {
    return <Text>Android Specifications</Text>;
  } else {
    return <Text>Pick a OS</Text>;
  }
};

function OsSelect(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Form
        initialValues={{
          category: null,
        }}
        onSubmit={(osSpec) => console.log(osSpec)}
      >
        <Picker items={categories} name="category" placeholder="Category" />
        <SubmitButton title="View Specs"  />
       {osSpec()}
      </Form>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but osSpec function doesn't respond to selected items in the categories. It only prints the text in else statement. How can I print details according to the selected items?